# PHP: IP address Check in text file

Tags: php, if-statement, reference, ip-address

I've been trying to grab a person's ip-address and then store it in a txt file when a person pays me to access certain content. When I store the IP in the txt file (logFile.txt), I want the person that paid the fee to be redirected to a content page that is only available for the people that have payed.  I also want to be able to redirect people that try and copy/paste the browser link to the "extra content".

I have code in my in my site that can log people's ip-address, but i want take that log file and cross reference it with the extra content page.

p.s. i've spent hours trying to figure this out with logging it to a text file to avoid mysql

I just need a general idea so i can wrap my head around this thing. not sure how to go about doing all this.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid SQL, a perfectly acceptable data storage medium? You can have an account system and then assign packages to accounts. This way you can even set expiration dates on subscriptions if they don't continue to pay.

Answer (score 4):

1. Why are you trying to avoid MySQL?  If two users do this at the same time, one of the writes to a log file could either be lost or blocked.  MySQL takes measures to prevent this.  It's also likely to be faster.
2. IP addresses are neither uniquely identifying (two users could be using one IP address) nor persistent to a given user (one user could be using two IP addresses).  I would be very upset if I paid for content, then couldn't access it any more because I don't have a static IP address.
3. Lastly (to more directly answer your question), you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the user's IP address and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write it to a file, but I'm not certain the way you're going about this is the best way.

Comment: Well what would you suggest? I'm trying to build a pay access content site without having to make the person login via user/pass and the content that is being payed for is only available for a 24 hour period.

Comment: I would say that the criteria that you'll need to meet are: **(1)** only the user who purchased the data can access it; **(2)** the user who purchased the data will be able to access it all the time (as long as it should be available); **(3)** the "login" info should be private to the user (i.e. other people can't guess it) **(4)** the "login" info should not be too private (e.g. social security number, credit card number, etc).  Due to these requirements, it seems like the easiest or most logical thing to me is just to go with a username/password system.  Why don't you want to?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the IP addresses in an array:

```
array{
   [0] => '192.168.1.1',
   [1] => '192.168.1.2',
}
```

Then before saving to your text file, use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) on the array. This will return a string that you can write to your text file.

To retrive your array, just use [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get the array back. Now, you should have an array of IP addresses which you can use the [standard array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to search, add and delete from.